# How to show CSS transitions only on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have added a transition onto a div, so that when it is hovered on, the color changes, bit like this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/78LWT/

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="transition"></div>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
#transition {
    background-color: #DA1E1E;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: .5s background-color;
    -webkit-transition: .5s background-color;
    -moz-transition: .5s background-color;
}
#transition:hover {
    background-color: #ADE1E1;
}
```

But here's the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/E295T/ (same CSS code as before), with this HTML code:

```
<div id="transition"></div><br />
<button onclick="recolortransitiondiv();">Recolor that div!</button>
```

And this JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
function recolortransitiondiv() {
    $("#transition").css("background-color", "#1EDA1E");
}
```

And that's where my problem comes in. When the color is to be changed by any method other than hovering over it (for example, when the div is active, or maybe when the div's properties are changed with JavaScript/jQuery), I don't want the transition to show, but I want the transition to show when I hover over the div.

Is there any way I can solve this problem? I am willing to use jQuery, plain JavaScript, CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you commented, if you want to prevent `transition` while the `background-color` is changed using `button`, the way to do is, to use `transition` on the `:hover` block

```
#transition:hover {
    background-color: #ADE1E1;
    transition: .5s background-color;
    -webkit-transition: .5s background-color;
    -moz-transition: .5s background-color;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/E295T/2/) *(`background-color` won't change though, read ahead)*

> Note: Anyways you will need the below solution as well, else your
>   `background-color` won't be changed

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/E295T/4/) *(If you care to `:hover` even after changing the `background-color` using jQuery)*

---

That is because jQuery adds inline CSS which has *highest preference/most specific* and hence, `:hover` `background-color` won't be respected, you will have to use `!important` in this case

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E295T/1/)

```
#transition:hover {
    background-color: #ADE1E1 !important;
}
```

---

Or else, it would be better, if you prefer adding and removing `class` using jQuery, instead of using `.css()` method, than you won't require `!important` as well.

Comment: I think you must have misunderstood. I don't want any transition to show on the div when the background color is changed with the button, but I want the transition to show when I hover over the div.

Comment: I must say, the only problem is that when I stop hovering over the div, there's no transition. But who cares? Accepted as answer.